# Leer correos de gmail desde powershell

Tags: powershell

Buen Día

He estado desarrollando un script en **Powershell** que inicia sesión en gmail con el modulo **Gmail.ps** y lee el mensaje de un correo en especifico.

De los correos que tengo en la bandeja solo he podido capturar el asunto que necesito mas no entra al mensaje **(Body)** de ese asunto, hay alguna manera de poder resolver este problema?

Agradezco mucho que me puedan ayudar.

```
# Obtiene credenciales seguras del correo electrónico
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (Unprotect-String -ProtectedString $PassEmail) -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Email, $SecurePassword

# Entra a gmail para leer el correo
$Gmail = New-GmailSession -Credential $Credentials # Crea una sesión de email

$Subject = "VEE - Nuevo registro de usuario" # Asunto del correo

$Inbox = $Gmail | Get-Mailbox # obtenga la bandeja de entrada
$Sbjt = $Inbox | Get-Message -Unread | Select-Object 'Subject' | Where-Object {$_.Subject -ccontains $Subject}
```

Answer (score 0):

no pude reproducir el problema, ya que luego de tener le módulo instalado genera un error al intentar iniciar la sesión de Gmail:

```
$Gmail = New-GmailSession
```

El error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "7" argument(s): "* NO [WEBALERT https://accounts.google.com/signin/continu
e?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs6Bl94pIFbWWVYrDHhyJ6Cn280LgWptlpK-60A5UkvPSPgLPug5XTffRxaWQE1H4yU1TlzU8HVOAvcx4AdNQXCRmwbFELE
FeoYwTblvDWfE0CJk1h3xVYGkSSjDTBgHXWZfuUpRrs2GHxLee00EZCwVf7e7uFKk9Hp8sc4UIF5115fzjLxEJP82iRP6VLBnedGj3wAvpmzYQp2bfqT7UQ
Y_DJatBo4BFphEtuPevaGzw1MejA] Web login required."
At C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Gmail.ps\Gmail.ps.psm1:16 char:16
+ ...  $session = New-Object -TypeName AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient -ArgumentList ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Pero lo que si pude encontrar en la documentación del módulo es lo siguiente:

> **Receive-Message**
>
> Fetches the whole message from the server (including
>   the body and the attachments).

Lo que debería solucionar tu problema, utilizándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
$Subject = "VEE - Nuevo registro de usuario" # Asunto del correo

$Inbox = $Gmail | Get-Mailbox # obtenga la bandeja de entrada
$Sbjt = $Inbox | Get-Message -Unread | Select-Object 'Subject' | Where-Object {$_.Subject -ccontains $Subject} | Receive-Message
$Msge = $Sbjt.Body
```